# JavaNullPointer for image

Tags: java, slick2d

I have this code for my player class:

```
public class Player {

private static Image front;

int posX = 400;
int posY = 300;

public void player() throws SlickException{
    init(null, null);
    render(null, null, null);
    update(null, null, (Integer) null);

}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
    front = new Image("res/steveFront.png");
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    front.draw(posX, posY);
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {

}
```

}

And this is my main game class:

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    map.render(gc, sbg, g);
    player.render(gc, sbg, g);
}
```

When I run the code it calls a javanullpointer exception on the

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    front.draw(posX, posY);
}
```

Why does it do this? I've been trying to figure this out for hours now. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that `front` is `null`.  Did `front` get properly initialized in the `init()` method?  That is, was it able to find `res/steveFront.png` and was that correctly processed into an instance of `Image`?

Comment: Player.front = new Image("res/steveFront.png");

Comment: Yes, everything is coded correctly, however it just doesn't want to work. I have drawn a map using an array the same way. I have no clue as to why it just won't work.

Comment: @case1352 I put that in the game class?

Comment: im just curious as to why 'front' is static.

Comment: @case1532 I can't believe I haven't thought of that... It worked, post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making variable 'front' not static

Answer (score 1):

Usually this means the path you give for the image is wrong

```
 front = new Image("res/steveFront.png")
```

If this is in your src folder, you have to use getResource

Comment: I'm using slick2d which has a resource manager built in, no need for any getResources methods. Thanks though! The problem has been solved.